# How to get the repeated ip address from the list of objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
 data = [{'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.1'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.1'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.2'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.2'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.3'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.1'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.1'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.1'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.2'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.5'}},
         {'META': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.1.2'}}]
```

Format will be as shown above.Now I want to get the repeated ip address in the whole list lets say if repeatition is more than 4 times I need to find that ip addresss and append to a list.

For example, If I had a ip with address x.x.1.1 that is repeated more than 4 times then I need to append that to a list 'A' like wise if x.x.1.2 is repeated more that 4 times need to append this to list 'A', using only javascript.I have a list of around 111000 objects. Anyone please tell me the easiest way to achieve this.

In the above example shown output should be like.

```
  A = ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.1']
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Find the count of each IP Address, using `Array.prototype.reduce`
var counter = data.reduce(function(result, currentObject) {
    var addr = currentObject.META.REMOTE_ADDR;
    result[addr] = (result[addr] || 0) + 1;
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(counter);
# { '192.168.1.1': 5,
#   '192.168.1.2': 4,
#   '192.168.1.3': 1,
#   '192.168.1.5': 1 }

# Filter the keys for which the count is greater than or equal to 4.
var result = [];
for (var key in counter) {
    if (counter[key] >= 4) {
        result.push(key);
    }
}
console.log(result);
# [ '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2' ]
```

In the counting section, `(result[addr] || 0)` means that, if the `addr` is already in `result` then use the value returned by `result[addr]` otherwise use `0`. Since we use `||`, it will pick the second value if the first value is falsy. If the `addr` is not in `result`, it will return `undefined`, which is falsy. That is why this code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array prototype to filter the array:  Edit: I see that you need it to repeat 4 or more times, simply add a counter to the loop

```
        Array.prototype.filter= function() {
            var result= []; var temp = {}; var count = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                if (result.indexOf(this[i]) == -1) {
                 count++;
                   //if this is a repeat add it to temp object and keep count:
                    temp[this[i]] = count;

                     if(temp[this[i]] == 4)
                      {
                     //if it repeats 4 times, for the same IP, store it reset counter:
                      count = 0;
                      result.push(this[i]);
                       }

                }
            }
            return result;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly:

Go through each item in your list, extract the value you are looking for, and add them to a hash - the key of the hash being your ip address, and the value being 1. If you come across one that is already in your hash, increment the value by one.

Once all your items have been processed, go through your dict, read the number of times it has occurred, and add them to your final list.

Here's a how-to for hashes in JS: http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html

Comment: Hi @AMADANON Inc can you please tell me a few lines of code.I am very new to javascript.

Comment: I have written up a step-by-step example at http://jsfiddle.net/Sptbf/1/ - jsfiddle is your friend for writing stuff like this, especially if you're going to share it. There is a "run" button in the top-left-hand corner.